# spring static mapping and load new image

Tags: image, spring, spring-mvc, mapping

Wery common problem, but no one solution:

I use mvc: resources mapping.

I save new image on my computer, and after I try to show it.

But NoRequestMapping for my image, because resourse mapping is static. And I downloaded image after this mapping.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Provide some code of your "resources" configuration please. I use <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/> and all works perfect

Comment: I added classpath, but the problem is in static content.